# Which information is returned when I type the name of a function in the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, object, attributes, decorator

I am trying to learn more about the attributes of Python objects. To that end, I would like to change the output I see in the Python interpreter when I enter the name of an object (in my particular case a function) in Python. How can I do that?

To elaborate, I defined a function returning a polynomial as follows:

```
def poly(coefs):

   @rename(coefs)
   def function(x):
      y,i = 0,0
      while i < len(coefs):
         y += coefs[i]*x**i
         i += 1 
    return y 

return function
```

The `docorator @rename(coefs)` makes sure that when I type `poly(coefs).__name__` in the interpreter a string of the associated polynomial function is returned. Now, suppose I define, for example, `a_polynomial = poly((1,2,3))` and type `a_polynomial` in the interpreter, the following is returned:

```
<function poly.<locals>.function>
```

From which information does Python return this reply? Instead of such a replay, I want to receive:

```
<function 3*x**2 + 2*x + 1 at 0x7f05d5be7b28>.
```

The polynomial function is already returned when I type `a_polynomial.__name__`. The last element is the location where the function is stored.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ BrenBarn: I am using Python 3.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In old python versions changing the `__name__` attribute is enough, however in recent python versions qualified names were introduced and the value returned by `__repr__` is based on the `__qualname__` attribute.

In this case the decorator would look like this:

```
def rename(coefs):
    # just a simple sketch for the polynomial representation.
    coefs_and_exps = reversed(list(enumerate(coefs)))
    str_repr = ' + '.join('{} * x**{}'.format(coef, i) for i, coef in coefs_and_exps)

    def decorator(func):
        func.__name__ = func.__qualname__ = str_repr
        return func

    return decorator
```

The best way to achieve what you want is to use a class instead of a function that returns a function:

```
class Poly:
    def __init__(self, coefs):
        self.coefs = coefs

    def __str__(self):
        coefs_and_pows = reversed(list(enumerate(self.coefs)))
        return ' + '.join('{}*x**{}'.format(coef, i) for i, coef in coefs_and_pows)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<function {} at 0x{:x}'.format(self, id(self))

    def __call__(self, x):
        return sum(coef * x**i for i, coef in enumerate(self.coefs))
```

And you can use the class in the same manner as you used your `poly` function:

```
In [23]: p = Poly((1, 2, 3))

In [24]: p
Out[24]: <function 3*x**2 + 2*x**1 + 1*x**0 at 0x7f87c0478588

In [25]: p(0)
Out[25]: 1

In [26]: p(3)
Out[26]: 34
```

Comment: Argh! You beat me to the punch! :)
Only significant difference with my version of this was that I prefer `__init__` to take `(self, *coefficients)` so that you can write `Poly(1, 2, 3)` instead of wrapping the coefficients in a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.3, [PEP 3155](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#proposal)  was implemented.  This gives classes and functions a new `__qualname__` attribute, and makes their `__str__` and `__repr__` use this instead of `__name__`.  What you are seeing is the value of this `__qualname__` attribute.  If you make your `rename` decorator set `__qualname__` as well, you'll get the result you want.